# How to convert List<ICollection<Patients>> to IEnumerable<Patients>

Tags: c#, linq

In my project I have `Medication` class so in this class it contains `ICollection<Patients> patients` property.

When I am getting list `Medication` then I am also getting these patients in `Medication` list object. So now I want separate this list from `Medication` and pass it to one method whose parameter is `IEnumerable<patients>`. I tried following code but conversion returns null.

```
  var pharmacyMedications = medications.Select(x => x.PharmacyMedications).ToList();

  var list = pharmacyMedications as IEnumerable<PharmacyMedication>;
```

This list I am getting null. So is there any way to achieve this conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You want [SelectMany](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1):

```
var pharmacyMedications = medications.SelectMany(x=>x.PharmacyMedications).ToList();

var list = pharmacyMedications as IEnumerable<PharmacyMedication>;
```

Comment: If you need an `IEnumerable` it makes little sense to call `ToList()` - the result of `SelectMany` is already an `IEnumerable`...

Comment: @ZoharPeled - I know, but it's what the question is trying to do.